# If object is contained in an array logic - Ruby

Tags: ruby

Conceptually I am trying to display a list of users in a search result list and have it say 'add as friend' if the user is not a friend and 'unfriend' if they are a friend.

The basic question I need answered to do this is how to say if an user ID exists in an array.  I created a friends array which contains all the id numbers of my friends and need to essentially write;

if user_in_search_results_id = id in the array, unfriend, otherwise add as friend.

the 'if user_in_search_results_id = id anywhere in the array' is where i am stuck.

I have tried .where(user_in_search_results_id == @friends) and that did not work.  @friends is friend array.  I have also tried the .select method without luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the include? method

```
user_in_search_results_id.each {|id| @friends.include?(id) ? unfriend(id) : add_as_friend(id)}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The basic question I need answered to do this is how to say if an user ID exists in an array.

You can do

```
friends_array.member?(user_id) ? "unfriend" : "add friend"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`Enumerable#detect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find).

```
@friends.detect { |id| user_in_search_results_id == id }
```